# Can I pass a parameter in the fetch callback?

Tags: javascript, callback, fetch-api

I need to pass an external parameter to fecth's callback.
I know that the callback is asynchronous but I need to have one or more external parameters inside it.

```
for(var m=0; m<10; m++){          
  fetch("https://www.apiexample.com?key=12345", {    
        method: 'GET'
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(result => {
        callbackFunction(result);        
    })
    .catch(error => alert('Ops! '+ error));
}

function callbackFunction(result){    
    console.log(result);      //ok
    //... HERE I WANT m VALUE
    
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Add a second parameter to `callbackFunction` and pass `m` when calling it?

Comment: @Palladium02 also `m` has to be declared as `let`

Comment: `callbackFunction(result, m);`

Comment: GREAT! Two great tips, I changed: for(let m=0;m<0 m++) { and callbackFunction(result,m); and function callbackFunction(result, m) {. 
Now it works correctly!

Answer (score -1):

`for(var m=0; m<10; m++){`
`fetch("https://www.apiexample.com?key=12345", {` 
 `method: 'GET'`
`})`
`.then(response => response.json())`
`.then(result => {`
`callbackFunction(result,`**value**`);` 
`})`
`.catch(error => alert('Ops! '+ error));`
`}`
`function callbackFunction(result,`**value**`)`
`{`
`console.log(result);`
`console.log(value);`
`}`